# How to add strings?

Tags: c++, char

I'm really new to C++ and I'm making a simple program

```
TCHAR CONFIG_NAME[32];
TCHAR CONFIG_PROCESSNAME[32];
int a = GetPrivateProfileString("Injection", "Name", "", CONFIG_DLLNAME, 32, path);
```

but I need to add a char* to it, because it needs the full path.
as a example, it's doing just

MyDLL.dll

but it needs to be doing

C:/folder/anotherfolder/mydog/MyDLL.dll

I tried doing

```
char* DLLLOC = "NULL";
sprintf(DLLLOC, "%s%s", dir, CONFIG_DLLNAME);
```

but it crashes

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `DLLLOC` hasn't had the sufficient space allocated to accommodate for your string concatenation.

A solution is to pre-allocate a large `char` buffer and use that instead, like below.

```
#define CONFIG_DLLNAME  "configdllname"

int main()
{
    char str[1024];
    const char* dir = "dir";
    sprintf(str, "%s%s", dir, CONFIG_DLLNAME);
    printf(str);
}
```

If the strings exceeds 1024 characters, you'll run into the same problem; welcome to string operations in C. :)

Also, since you marked this is a C++ question, is there a reason you're not using `std::string`? This would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
wstring DLLLOC(dir);
DLLLOC.append(CONFIG_DLLNAME);
```

this preserves with buffer overflow (and yes windows has a limit of 255 characters in path, so you can assert later than size is within limits)

Comment: what if concatenated string is greater than 255 chars??

Comment: Then the behavior is undefined you will stomp on random memory beyond the end of your buffer.. you could use MAX_PATH since it is a path after all.. or just compute the size based on the length of your other two strings.

Comment: I dont know the environment he is working but in Windows, usually a path is considered to be MAX_PATH (260) characters long. Since he didnt mention the environment, I just used a common constant.

Comment: @Rob: yes that's why it needs better solution. stack overflow can wreak havoc. I prefer using string/wstring objects

Comment: TCHAR is windows i guess

Answer (score 0):

Your `char* DLLLOC` only has five characters  worth of space in it.  (4 for the letters "NULL" and one more fore the null terminator (a zero byte that marks the end of strings in c++.  You need to make sure `char* DLLLOC` points to an area large enough to contain the strings your putting into it.

You might try allocating the space dynamically:

```
// c style
char* DLLLOC = malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(CONFIG_DLLNAME)+1);
// c++ style
char* DLLLOC = new char[strlen(dir)+strlen(CONFIG_DLLNAME)+1];
```

(You can use `sizeof` here if `dir` and `config_DLLNAME` are arrays of chars and not pointers to chars.)

Or, you can declare the space before hand:

```
char DLLLOC[256];
```

For this to work, you have to be sure the final string wont be longer that the size of the array.